# What is the best practice to access one Room table by multiple view interfaces?

Tags: android, android-room, clean-architecture

let's say that I have only one table in the app that caches products.
the main interface presents products that come from API that provides all products.
the search interface searches a product by name and there is an API for that.

Now let's assume that it is required to cache the result of the search results.. the data from API will be just a list of products. The insert function will replace the duplicated products entities. However, **HOW should we recognize the products inserted in the table to be presented in the search interface as the cached version??**

In similar situations, I used a field to save the request used to fetch the data and made it a candidate key to be part of the primary key. I thought also about making a duplicate product table to handle search results but it looked boilerplate code to me.

I couldn't phrase the problem properly to find a better solution online.

Comment: it's basically impossible to answer without showing any code, but it also feels like you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist, or worse, you're making a problem which doesn't have to exist just because you want to apply a certain architectural design

Comment: it is not a coding problem. it's just about the best way to approach this. so in brief, one table is accessed by two activities and each one of them should present a different list of the same object type (product in the example).

And the original problem was too complex to be described here like, the products table was accessed by multiple activities with different scenarios where each one of them can show a different list of that caching table.